# голосовой помощник, добавление любого слова

Tags: python

Други, помогите в направление на путь истинный))))

Задача. Прописать в код функционал, что бы программка, при прослушивании микрофона понимала не только шаблонный текст из списка (hello), но и **плюс** какое то случайное слово сказанное в микрофон.

Например:

В списке hello слово шаблон "Привет", жёсткие рамки, ответ программы так же "Привет"

Хотелось бы:

Сказанное слово "Привет" + случайное произнесённое слово (например: "Привет друг" или "Привет Вася") воспринимался кодом так же, как просто - "Привет", ответ программы так же - "Привет" то есть игнорируем по сути второе сказанное слово, к слову Привет.

Я не волшебник и только учусь, прошу направить хотя бы в нужное русло) Мучал регулярки, но что то всё время идёт не так. Заранее спасибо

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import random

mic = sr.Microphone(device_index=2)

ansver_list = ['здравствуйте', 'приветствую', 'привет', 'рад вас слышать']

def speek(words):
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
    engine.setProperty('voice', voices[3].id)
    engine.say(words)
    engine.runAndWait()

def command():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with mic as source:
        audio = r.listen(source=mic)
    try:
        query = r.recognize_google(audio_data=audio, language='ru-RU').lower()
    except:
        query = command()
    return query


hello = ['привет', 'здравствуй', 'приветствую']

def talking(query):

    if query in hello:
        print(speek(words=random.choice(ansver_list)))
    else:
        print(speek(words='я не понял ваш запрос'))

while True:
    talking(command())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то типа такого:

```
if query.split()[0].lower() in hello:
```

То есть делим фразу на слова, берём первое слово, приводим в нижний регистр, после этого ищем в списке.

Comment: благодарствую. надо попробовать.

Comment: спасибо. жаль что доп. вопросы по теме нужно задавать через создание нового вопроса. ну что делать. правила есть правила. жду 40 минут для создания следующего вопроса. если Вас не затруднит, буду признателен за ответ